# Dispose SoftArtisans ExcelWriter objects from memory? It shows Memory Out Of Exception

Tags: officewriter

While generating excelsheets , i am able to generate 5 sheets at run time , but on the 6th sheet , the memory consumption hits till 2.8GB , and it crashes out.
I am using C# .net with OW API to generate dynamic sheets based on DB datasets

Comment: A few questions: 1) Are you using Worksheets.CreateSheet() or Worksheets.CopySheet() to generate your worksheets? 2) If you are using CopySheet, what is on the worksheet that is being copied? (i.e. lots of formulas, charts) 3) If you are using CreateSheet(), what other API calls are you making after the sheet is created? 4) What is the size of your original file? 5) Would it be possible to post some of the code that you are using to generate your worksheets?

Comment: A couple of other questions: What version of OfficeWriter are you using?  How many rows and columns of data are on each sheet?

Comment: Note: OfficeWriter is entirely managed code so it is not necessary to call Dispose on any objects